# Show $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$ is closed with respect to the operation $a\ast b = ab + a + b$

Tags: group-theory

Consider $(\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\},*)$, where
$$a*b:=ab+a+b \qquad a,b \in \Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}.$$
We have to prove that it's an Abelian group. While it's easy to show how the properties of associativity, identity element, inverse element and commutativity hold, how do we prove the **closure**?

Comment: Hint: $ab + a + b + 1 = (a + 1)(b + 1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to show that $ab+a+b$ is not equal to $-1$, if $a$ and $b$ are both not equal to $-1$ to begin with. This can be shown by assuming that $ab+a+b=-1$ and showing that necessarily $a$ or $b$ equals $-1$.

Reorganize things as $a(b+1)+b=-1$, which leads to $a(b+1)+b+1=0$. Factor this to $(a+1)(b+1)=0$. Conclude.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

If $ab+a+b=-1$, then either $a=-1$ or $b=-1$.